# (C++) AspectC++ intercept methods of derived class

Tags: c++, intercept, aspect

This may be a dumb question, but I couldn't find the answer after searching for hours.

Using AspectC++, we can define pointcuts, which represent something that, once matched, is intercepted. For instance, I can do

```
pointcut pc() = call("% Base::%(...)");
```

so that any `advice` that uses the pointcut `pc` will intercept any call to some method of class `Base`. This works even if, later, a subclass `Sub` of `Base` is created: `pc` will intercept calls to methods of `Sub` as well. Now, what I want is to intercept methods *only* of `Sub`, that is, methods of `Sub` which are not present in `Base`. How can we make `pc()` intercept any method of any subclass of `Base` that is eventually created, but not methods of `Base` itself?

Comment: Why do you need to make that distinction?  Public base class methods are normally treated as functionally equal to the derived class methods.  There is no practical difference, in other words.  Can you make the base class members `protected`?

Comment: Because I do not want methods of the base class to be intercepted, but only those that are eventually added by the developer in their subclass. Is that possible?

Comment: OK, but how do you get around the problem that (by virtue of inheritance) public base class methods are functionally identical to derived class methods?  How do you tell them apart?

Comment: Good point, so I just tested now and, using aspectc++, I could simply define the pointcut as `call("% Sub::%(...)")` and somehow it tells inherited methods apart from non-inherited ones. The question is: how to make that work for any subclass?